# "Enter" key not working in C# Winform number guessing (Hangman) game

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written the C# code below for a number guessing game (Hangman). Everything seems to work perfectly, but I am trying to implement some sort of while (or do-while) or for loop into the application but when doing so, it causes irregular behavior, and sometimes causes the application to freeze.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hangman
{
    public partial class frmHangman : Form
    {
        private Bitmap[] hangmanImages = {Properties.Resources.hangman1, Properties.Resources.hangman2,
                                        Properties.Resources.hangman3, Properties.Resources.hangman4,
                                        Properties.Resources.hangman5, Properties.Resources.dead, Properties.Resources.yay};
    //hangman images to be displayed into the game

    int guessedNumber = 0;
    int numGuesses = 0;
    const int maxCount = 6;
    static Random rand = new Random();
    int computerNumber = rand.Next(1, 101);
    static string msg;

    public frmHangman()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        init();
    }

    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        guessedNumber = int.Parse(txtUserNumber.Text);
            if (guessedNumber > computerNumber)
            {
                msg = "Should be lower than " + guessedNumber;
                txtUserNumber.Focus();
                hangmanPicture.Image = hangmanImages[numGuesses];
                numGuesses++;
            }
            else if (guessedNumber < computerNumber)
            {
                msg = "Should be greater than " + guessedNumber;
                txtUserNumber.Focus();
                hangmanPicture.Image = hangmanImages[numGuesses];
                numGuesses++;
            }
            if (guessedNumber == computerNumber)
            {
                msg = "Great, you got it";
                hangmanPicture.Image = hangmanImages[6];
                btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                newGame.Visible = true;
                noBtn.Visible = true;
                yesBtn.Visible = true;
                yesBtn.Checked = false;
                numGuesses = 0;
            }
            else if (numGuesses == maxCount)
            {
                msg = "You lose. It was " + computerNumber;
                hangmanPicture.Image = hangmanImages[5];
                btnGuess.Enabled = false;
                newGame.Visible = true;
                noBtn.Visible = true;
                yesBtn.Visible = true;
                yesBtn.Checked = false;
                numGuesses = 0;

            }
            labelResult.Text = msg;
        }

        private void init()
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            computerNumber = rand.Next(1, 101);

            numGuesses = 0;
            hangmanPicture.Image = null;
            labelResult.Text = "Guess a number between 1-100";
            btnGuess.Enabled = true;
            txtUserNumber.Clear();
            txtUserNumber.Focus();
            newGame.Visible = false;
            noBtn.Visible = false;
            yesBtn.Visible = false;

        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            init();//"yes" button at the end of the game to prompt user to play again
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();//"no" button at the end of game to prompt user to end the game

        }

        private void btnGuess_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                btnGuess.PerformClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick one - calling `rand.Next(1, 100)` will generate numbers from 1 to 99, not 1 to 100.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will make the change :).

Comment: You mean because the radio button is check already when the second game starts? I made the game, assuming a few things. Might not have it correct.

Comment: juanvan you are correct. That seemed to have done the trick. Also, I just found out that the Enter key does not work, can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: not related to your question, static `static Random rand = new Random();` seems to be useless, because your `init` creates another random.

Comment: @kurakura88 - It probably should be the other way around. The `init` declaration is the one that should go. There is only ever a need to declare `Random` once per thread.

Comment: I believe you need to enable the form to recognize key events by setting the Form.KeyPreview property to true then handle the event for the form not the button.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I set the KeyPreview property to true, removed the random number generator in init(), set the radiobutton checked value to false on init(), and fixed the first random number generator to include numbers 1 - 100. I believe that takes care of all the issues I was seeing. I have one additional question, if I was to include some sort of loop, how would I go about that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the PreviewKey of the form to true.
You can do so by going to the designer,
selecting the form and setting the value to true of PreviewKey, all of this is in the properties window.